# Java: ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java

What is the correct thread safe collection to map an integer and a string in Java?
Is ConcurrentHashMap the right way to go?

```
private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<int, bool> chm;
```

What is wrong with the above declaration. Eclipse says "Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token"

Comment: I think it's extremely unlikely you actually want `volatile` there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This maps an `Integer` to a `String`.  In Java, generics must use reference types (Integer, Boolean, etc.), not primitives (int, boolean, etc.)

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> chm;
```

I doesn't need to be volatile, except in the unlikely event you'll be putting new maps into the field from more than one thread.  The map itself will take care of synchronizing mutations.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `private final`. CHM does take care of its internal state, but only after it's properly constructed and is visible to the thread. `final` would guarantee that.

Comment: I am setting the maps from two threads. So volatile is needed right?

Comment: @Mahatma, what do you mean setting the maps?  Are you setting the field (chm = ...), or just calling [put](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)?  You only potentially want volatile for the first.  @Zwei, good suggestion; that should help ensure it's used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you understand that even when using ConcurrentHashMap you can still get inconsistencies, especially if you have a read/write/read area of your code. Multi-operations on that map still need to be synchronized as one "transcation".